# Local file upload: File.open or StringIO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

My application allows a user to upload an image and then create different versions of that image (e.g. aligned and cropped with another image). The intermediate step is that I need to copy the uploaded file to another object and process it. The easiest way to do this is to upload it locally.

From the carrierwave wiki, [they suggest using a modified version of StringIO](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Upload-from-a-string-in-Rails-3).

On the carreirwave readme, they also suggest using File.open (something like `obj.image=File.open('path_to_file')`.

I've also found references to using `fixture_file_upload` from `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` (usually in testing, but I'm unsure why it is restricted to that environment).

Can anyone give me a good explanation on the pros and cons (if any) of using these methods?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how stringIO works, but you want to be very careful not to load the whole file into memory, or you'll have some pretty large potential memory increases on your ruby processes.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered one major difference, at least in the context of carrierwave. If you use carrierwave with the `move_to_cache` option set to true and mount your upload column with `File.open`, the file given to `File.open` will be moved, while with `StringIO`, it won't.